# What is called when `log_every_n_steps` of a pytorch lightning trainer is reached?

Tags: python, logging, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

PL lightning trainer offers a parameter `log_every_n_steps` which it states controls "How often to add logging rows", however what is the function actually being called here? We can do our own logging every step with the example code below

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    self.log("performance", {"acc": acc, "recall": recall})
```

But is the trainer doing the same at the every nth step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log_every_n_steps` will make the training log every n batches. This value is used by `self.log` if `on_step=True`. If you want a less bloated log-file, with the results per epoch only, you could do `self.log(metrics, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)`

Comment: How `log_every_n_steps` affects the validation log?

Answer (score 1):

The `Trainer` object in PyTorch Lightning has a `log_every_n_steps` parameter that specifies the number of training steps between each logging event. If the logging interval is larger than the number of training batches, then logs will not be printed for every training epoch.

To resolve this warning, you can either decrease the logging interval by setting a lower value for `log_every_n_steps`, or you can increase the number of training batches by increasing the batch size or the number of training samples.

```
trainer = Trainer(log_every_n_steps=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of where (in which hook) you call `self.log(...)`, the `log_every_n_steps` overrides it. Hence, the configured loggers cannot log more frequently than this. Its default value is set to `50` as of lightning version 2.0.

Also, I'm able to log_every_n_steps without setting `on_step` (default=None), as opposed to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72949099/17550518).